# How to change the location/position of the Side drawer in nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I'm learning nativescript.I want to change the direction of sidedrawer in my app (now it's opened from left) that is opened from right.How can I do it?

Here is my code:

app.component.html:

```
<RadSideDrawer tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton>
    <StackLayout tkDrawerContent class="sideStackLayout">
        <StackLayout class="sideTitleStackLayout">
            <Label text="Navigation Menu"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout class="sideStackLayout">
            <Label text="Primary" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Social" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Promotions" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Labels" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Important" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Starred" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Sent Mail" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Drafts" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <Button text="Close Drawer" (tap)="onCloseDrawerTap()"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout tkMainContent>
        <Label [text]="mainContentText" textWrap="true" class="drawerContentText"></Label>
        <Button text="OPEN DRAWER" (tap)="openDrawer()" class="drawerContentButton"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

app.component.ts :

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
import { Page } from "ui/page";
import { ActionItem } from "ui/action-bar";
import { Observable } from "data/observable";
import { RadSideDrawerComponent, SideDrawerType } from "nativescript-telerik-ui-pro/sidedrawer/angular";
import { RadSideDrawer } from 'nativescript-telerik-ui-pro/sidedrawer';


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "tk-sidedrawer-getting-started",
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
    private _mainContentText: string;

    constructor(private _changeDetectionRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    @ViewChild(RadSideDrawerComponent) public drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent;
    private drawer: RadSideDrawer;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.drawer = this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer;
        this._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.mainContentText = "SideDrawer for NativeScript can be easily setup in the HTML definition of your page by defining tkDrawerContent and tkMainContent. The component has a default transition and position and also exposes notifications related to changes in its state. Swipe from left to open side drawer.";
    }

    get mainContentText() {
        return this._mainContentText;
    }

    set mainContentText(value: string) {
        this._mainContentText = value;
    }

    public openDrawer() {
        this.drawer.showDrawer();
    }

    public onCloseDrawerTap() {
       this.drawer.closeDrawer();
    }

}
```

app.module.ts:

```
 import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";
import { NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule } from 'nativescript-telerik-ui-pro/sidedrawer/angular'

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [NativeScriptModule, NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RadSideDrawer from the nativescript-telerik0ui plugin supports changing its location/position via its `drawerLocation` property. That property can be set to:

- Top
- Bottom
- Left
- Right

You can refer for more information in the documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/SideDrawer/location) or the sdk Angular examples [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/tree/release/sdkAngular/app/sidedrawer).

Comment: Thanke you so much.It worked for me.I changed the openDrawer function.                                                                                                       public openDrawer() {
        this.drawer.drawerLocation=SideDrawerLocation.Right;
        this.drawer.showDrawer();
        
    }

Comment: How would you change the content that displays, not only the location where it display, so left is the menu, but right is the settings,

Comment: For that you will need to change the drawerContent property of the RadSideDrawer instance, more details here: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/radsidedrawer.html#drawercontent

Answer (score 0):

```
import { RadSideDrawerComponent, SideDrawerType } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/angular";
import { SideDrawerLocation } from 'nativescript-ui-sidedrawer';

private currentLocation: SideDrawerLocation;
      onOpenDrawerTap() {
            this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer.drawerLocation = SideDrawerLocation.Top; //change location here Top, Right, Left, Bottom
            this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer.showDrawer();
        }
```

refer this link in nativescript playground [sidedrawer from top](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=mnMzIf)